# Remove top graph from Apache eCharts DataZoom

Tags: components, echarts

We're looking for a component to show a slider with indications of data within it that we want to use as a filter for data we're showing. The data will be shown as a grid.
We've looked at the Apache eCharts DataZoom (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-dataZoom) and find the bottom slider to be perfect for the job, but we do not need the top graph. Is there a way to get the DataZoom to do this, or is the slider a component that we can use directly? Can't seem to find anything about either options in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to use the dataZoom component without the graph. You could just make the graph invisable if that is an option for you: [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-simple&code=DYUwLgBARghgziCBeCBqAdiA7hAIjMEACgEYBOANgA4AaCMugZgEoBuAKFEgHtN8BPZBABMAFggAqCIwoAGWZIgl5sjlwgATAohQBtALprwmgjCG6AsgQAWAOgBOMdBu4BbIs0WN5h9gDNuewgidQBLIRJWCHCAHhEVVWjUVE8Ab3YICAA3GCD0bhwUTBx8QiIiWAQ0FF4QAWY2DJNCWwAHAFc4ayJdfKxbAHNwADF24GAATRBcjzo-wfALXjBuz1QlOYKFsFLiZn1bACtuUPQiAHIAenOGjkytMBg2zu6rFYdududyt7tHZzcHggAFoILJbABWTxSYQKdYPGC6cKgkj6W7sAC-7HY3FaYFCvCE6UyAA8AIIk0JwABcEGJmQgYH4rRAtPOAGNtANAvxzjQmvdTLSHiB-QyIF0CrS_DBgAgmhixRB-BSqbTUpKsNLZQhFU0EQAtbhuWm6AV082ZOCPexgWmyJXikDOWnKc1YzL6JUIeyhEA0iBm8X08XoGCuVkQc7DGAAa0QpRgfMtjOZkfOwFOIGT4syoUIrgAykzQOqU5l2dxgIE2WB_nBWrlnWBzim9bnmjBhaZ3U19JjWEA)

Comment: Great. Thanks. We ended doing the same. So we'll keep that as our solution, if there are no other ways of doing this.